How to solve non-homogenous trig-function coefficient system of 1st order ODEs?
I'm trying to solve the following system of 1st order, non-homogenous differential equations:
$$x' = \frac{1}{2} sin(t) x - \frac{1}{2} y$$
$$y' = \frac{1}{2} cos(t) x - \frac{sin(t)}{1 - cos(t)} y$$
I've read up on the Laplace transform, but I'm not sure how to use it when I have these trig function coefficients. Is there a way to use this transform, or another method to solve this one?

I thought all systems of linear first order diffeq’s had a solution. Maybe that was just constant coefficient ones?

$$\begin{align}
&\iff \cases{x'\sin(t) = \frac{1}{2}\sin^2(t)x-\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)y\\(1-\cos(t))y'=\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(t) -\cos^2(t)  \right)x -\sin(t)y}\\
&\implies  x'\sin(t)-(1-\cos(t))y'=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(t))x +\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)y\\
&\iff 2\sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right) \left(x'\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right) - y' \sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)   \right) = \sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)\left(\sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)x+\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)y \right)\\
&\iff x'\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right) - y' \sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)  = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)x+\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)y \right)\\
&\iff \left( x\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)- y \sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)  \right)' = 0\\
&\iff \color{red}{ x\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)- y \sin\left( \frac{t}{2}\right) = c=\text{const}} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
From $(1)$, we deduce that
$$x(t) =\tan\left( \frac{t}{2}\right) \cdot y(t)+ \frac{c}{\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)} \tag{2}$$
Use $(2)$ to the second initial equation of $y'(t)$, we have:
$$\color{red}{y'(t)= \left(\frac{1}{2} \cos(t)\tan\left( \frac{t}{2}\right) - \frac{\sin(t)}{1-\cos(t)}\right)y(t) + \frac{1}{2}\cos(t)\cdot \frac{c}{\cos\left( \frac{t}{2}\right)}} \tag{3} $$
The first order differential equation $(3)$ can be solved analytically. I let you do the calculation.
And after obtaining $y(t)$, it's easy to get $x(t)$ from $(2)$.
Q.E.D.

Thank you. I had already found a way to reduce the expression into all terms with double angles, and set t = 2 theta.
